# Jump conditions not being implemented correctly in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to concert the following pseudocode into assembly code-
[image]

This is the code that I currently have. While the code builds successfully, it's going through both the LESSER and GREATER conditions when debugging. I can't seem to figure out what's making this happen. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
.data
    array1 BYTE 13h,14h,15h,16h
    array2 BYTE 12h,13h,14h,15h
    sample1 BYTE 30h
    sample2 BYTE 5h
    length1 BYTE LENGTHOF array1
    length2 BYTE LENGTHOF array2
    index BYTE 0
    maxlength DWORD 4
    exp1 WORD ?

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, 0  ;serves as the index
    L1:
    mov bl, array1[esi]
    mov cl, array2[esi]
    cmp bl, cl
    jg GREATER
    jl LESSER

    GREATER: 
    mov al, bl
    mul sample1
    mov bx, ax
    mov al, cl
    mul sample2
    mov cx, ax
    mov ax, bx
    mov dx, 0
    div cx

    LESSER:
    mov exp1, 0

    inc esi
    cmp esi, maxlength  ;while condition
    jl L1
```

Comment: The cpu does not know about blocks. After the `div cx` it will continue to the next instruction, which happens to be in the `LESSER:` case. You will need to add a jump to skip that block. PS: you don't seem to store the result in `exp1`.

Comment: @JesterWould it work if I reversed the jump conditions?

Comment: No, it would have the same problem.